# How to fix '[AuthenticationError.OAUTH_TOKEN_INVALID @ ; trigger:'<null>']'

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

I'm setting up integration with Google Adwords. 
I use Google's library `googleads/googleads-php-lib`.

I recive a `refreshToken` from Google, but when I try to get client data I get an exception from soap:

[AuthenticationError.OAUTH_TOKEN_INVALID @ ; trigger:'null']

My code:

```
$oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
   ->from($config)
   ->build();

$session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
   ->from($config)
   ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
   ->withDeveloperToken('uBFZEv...-lx1g')
   ->build();


/** @var CampaignService $campaignService */
$campaignService = $this->adWordsServices->get($session, CampaignService::class);

$selector = new Selector();
$selector->setFields(['Id', 'Name']);

$campaigns = $campaignService->get($selector); // exception appears here
dump($campaigns);
```

If call `$oAuth2Credential->fetchAuthToken();`
I get `access_token` and everything looks good.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: same issue. I pass the `refresh_token` to it

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Did anyone managed to resolve this?